# Как собрать проект x86 и x64 одновременно?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

Допустим есть проект MainProject.vcxproj и проект HelpersLib.vcxproj. MainProject включает HelpersLib как ссылку на проект. Как можно собрать 2 версии проекта MainProject(x64+x86) независимо от того какая сейчас разрядность выбрана?

Если бы небыло ссылки на проект, то можно было собрать 1 проект из другого:

```
<!-- ... -->    
<Target Name="MyTargetName" AfterTargets="Build">
        <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Properties="Platform=Win32;" />
        <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Properties="Platform=x64;" />
</Target>
```

Если же используется ссылка на проект, я так понимаю HelpersLib собирается для той платформы которая стоит в диспетчере конфигураций, и он же используется при ручной сборки MainProject для другой платформы (т.е. x86 конфликтует с x64).

Есть какое-либо решение? Visual Studio пакетная сборка не интересует.

Comment: Напиши батник. Загрузка окружения 86 - сборка - загрузка 64 - сборка

Comment: Ну батник не лучше пакетной сборки VS. Хочется чтоб нажать ПКМ на проект -> cобрать -> собрался проект для x64 и x86. Мне кажется должно быть решение через msbuild.

Comment: *"ПКМ на проект -> cобрать -> собрался проект для x64 и x86"* ну так это же и есть пакетная сборка Visual Studio и осуществляется она посредством msbuild. Указываете в аргументах несколько платформ и конфигураций - они и собираются